# hokuyo at /dev/ttyACM0 change default settings

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, hokuyo-node, hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

With our robot we are using a single hokuyo laser scanner for obstacle detection.

As software we are using ROS-Hydro and the [Hokuyo node](http://wiki.ros.org/hokuyo_node) here. We got everything working, but startup is kinda cumbersome:

- Depending on order of bootup the hokuyo will be either `/dev/ttyACM0` or `/dev/ttyACM1`, so we created a udev rule to always have it at `/dev/sensors/hokuyo`.
- Therefore we always need to set the port before starting up: `rosparam set hokuyo_node/port /dev/sensors/hokuyo` ([taken from here](http://wiki.ros.org/hokuyo_node/Tutorials/UsingTheHokuyoNode#Setting_Parameters) )

Of course, this is scriptable, but I'm looking for a better way to change this in some configuration file or similar.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213969/hokuyo-at-/dev/ttyacm0-change-default-settings/) by [85pando](https://answers.ros.org/users/23227/85pando/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use a launch file. Check out the roslaunch docs for further information.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2